# How to create a new video out of two videos and an imageView in an encompassing frame?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have a parent view that contains two views with AVPlayerLayers, and one UIImageView. I would like to combine all of these into one new video that would capture all the content of the parent view.

I looked into ReplayKit but that doesn't capture contents of AVPlayers; it doesn't give me access to the video; and it captures the whole screen rather than a particular view or frame.

My general approach has been to iterate through the videos frame by frame, capture the image of the frame, set them in an imageView that I overlay over the playerLayer, and then capture an image of the parent view using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` -- and then make a video out of all of these images.

I've tried a handful of AVFoundation options, but overall their performance is not that good. Here are some of the options I've tried, always attempting the above pattern.

1. set the video frames simply by using `videoPlayer.seek(to: frame)` -- but this method is pretty slow: it takes about 42 seconds per 15 second video to iterate through each frame this way.
2. getting all the video frames asynchronously with `AVAssetImageGenerator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously`, and then iterating through those in the above pattern. This is very memory intensive as I have an image for each frame of both videos. I can chunk the work to avoid a memory crash, but overall this method is still rather slow and with this batching-complexity isn't really that much better than the first method.
3. get each frame concurrently using `AVAssetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: frame, actualTime: nil)`, but this isn't any faster than the first option.
4. Use an `AVAssetReader` and iterate through each frame using `copyNextSampleBuffer` -- no real improvement over any of the above options.

There are some things I could probably do to optimize processing, but I don't think they solve the fundamental problems mentioned above. For example, I could perhaps cut down the video quality, or trim it since some of the video is not visible within its frame, or reduce the frame rate, but I would rather avoid those if possible.

At this point I'm thinking I might have to use Metal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, but I would have thought this was pretty much trivial with AVMutableVideoComposition and AVAssetExportSession. This allows you to specify layers to position your videos and image and then just feed the whole thing out as a single video.

Comment: I'm currently going down the path of using AVMutableVideoComposition. It seems like it will likely do the trick. This will require me to map the view layout of the parent view to that of the video as a whole, which is doable...just a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone a different route which seems like it will do the trick. You can examine a working version in this [repo](https://github.com/plflanagan/VideoMerger), but most of the code is below. The code is not production ready/very clean, and is merely a proof of concept -- hence the use of `!`, long functions, repetition, etc.

```
func overlapVideos() {

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        // make main video instruction
        let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        guard let pathUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_7165", withExtension: "MOV") else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }


        // make first video track and add to composition
        let firstAsset = AVAsset(url: pathUrl)

        // timeframe will match first video for this example
        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: firstAsset.duration)


        guard let firstTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        try! firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: firstAsset.duration), of: firstAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: .zero)

        // add layer instruction for first video
        let firstVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: firstTrack)
        let firstMove = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 500, y: 400)
        let firstScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

        firstVideoLayerInstruction.setTransform(firstMove.concatenating(firstScale), at: .zero)

        mainInstruction.layerInstructions.append(firstVideoLayerInstruction)


        // make second video track and add to composition
        let secondAsset = AVAsset(url: pathUrl)

        guard let secondTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        try! secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: secondAsset.duration), of: secondAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: .zero)

        // add layer instruction for second video
        let secondVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: secondTrack)
        let secondMove = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -100, y: -100)
        let secondScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

        secondVideoLayerInstruction.setTransform(secondMove.concatenating(secondScale), at: .zero)

        mainInstruction.layerInstructions.append(secondVideoLayerInstruction)


        // make third video track and add to composition
        let thirdAsset = AVAsset(url: pathUrl)

        guard let thirdTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        try! thirdTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: thirdAsset.duration), of: thirdAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: .zero)

        // add layer instruction for third video
        let thirdVideoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: thirdTrack)
        let thirdMove = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)
        let thirdScale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

        thirdVideoLayerInstruction.setTransform(thirdMove.concatenating(thirdScale), at: .zero)

        mainInstruction.layerInstructions.append(thirdVideoLayerInstruction)


        // make video composition
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
        videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 640, height: 480)


        // export
        let searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectory = searchPaths[0]
        let filePath = documentDirectory.appending("output.mov")
        let outputUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            try! fileManager.removeItem(at: outputUrl)
        }

        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exporter.outputFileType = .mov
        exporter.outputURL = outputUrl

        exporter.exportAsynchronously {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                // play video, etc.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be difficult because what you're trying to do is to add a hook to snatch the composited outcome of the GPU that's already rendered, by capturing a stream of the raw image buffer from a view, in real time. This can hardly be efficient in terms of CPU/GPU, or memory usage. You might be successful if you somehow have access to GPU's native API to get that composited raw buffer in a more direct way, but it is awkward.

The more natural way of doing this would be - to do the proper video composition as soon as you get the required materials(videos, images, etc.), and then show the processed outcome to the user and manipulate it as you like(dump the data as a file, etc).

In short, try to google "ios video composition". AFAIK, AVFoundation provides related functionalities. You might also want to look into some of the libraries like [this](https://github.com/VideoFlint/Cabbage) to get less bothered from writing all the low level code yourself.